# * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > org/bouncycastle/operator/OperatorCreationException

Tags: flutter, dart

In Every flutter build, even in a fresh one, I'm getting the same error[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmE8i.png)

```
lib/main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/aabirsark/Desktop/projects/rx_converter/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> org/bouncycastle/operator/OperatorCreationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 28s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Pls help me with this... I'm really stuck with it and can't make more progress pls help!!!

Comment: Please no images of error.

Comment: I got the same issue, and i solved this issue by changing gradle to latest version in the path: Android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip

Answer (score 2):

6 Steps:

1. click on `Project Structure` (folder with 3 dot icon next to Stop icon).

`Project Structure --> Project Settings --> Project`

under `Project SDK:` Select `Android API 30 Platform`

click `Apply` --> `OK`

2. click on `Project Structure` (folder with 3 dot icon next to Stop icon).

`Project Structure --> Project Settings --> Modules`

click `+` icon --> `Apply` --> `OK`

3. Use latest Gradle
4. Set the JDK version to Embedded JDK

For MAC:

`Android Studio > Preferences... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle Under Gradle JDK`

choose the Embedded JDK option. Click OK.

For windows:

`select File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle Under Gradle JDK`

choose the Embedded JDK option.

5. --add-opens If you have to allow code on the class path to do deep reflection to access nonpublic members, then use the --add-opens runtime option.

Some libraries do deep reflection, meaning setAccessible(true), so they can access all members, including private ones. You can grant this access using the --add-opens option on the java command line. No warning messages are generated as a result of using this option.

If --illegal-access=deny, and you see IllegalAccessException or InaccessibleObjectException messages at runtime, you could use the --add-opens runtime option, basing the arguments upon the information shown in the exception message.

6. config jvm option Since version 9, the Java compiler can be configured to produce bytecode for an older Java version while making sure the code does not use any APIs from a more recent version. Gradle now supports this release flag on CompileOptions directly for Java compilation. This option takes precedence over the properties described below.

Due to a bug in Java 9 that was fixed in Java 10, Gradle cannot leverage the release flag when compiling with Java 9.

This should solve..